# For finite $G$ s.t. $\forall n\mid |G|\exists$ at most one $H_n<G$ with $|H_n|=n$, for $g,h\in G$ s.t. $|h|\mid |g|$, we have $h\in\langle g\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The question I'm working on states the following:  Let $G$ be a finite group such that for every $n \mid |G|$, there exists at most one subgroup $H_n < G$ of order $|H_n|=n$.  Let $g,h \in G$ such that $|h| \mid |g|$.  Prove that $h \in \langle g \rangle$.  $\textbf{Hint}$: Prove that every subgroup of $G$ is normal.

Proving every subgroup of $G$ is normal is pretty immediate, by observing that $gHg^{-1} = H$ by the condition on $G$ for any subgroup $H<G$ and $g \in G$.

From the hint, I know that $\langle g \rangle \lhd G$, so I began to look at $G/\langle g \rangle$, and tried to prove that $h \langle g \rangle = \langle g \rangle$, but was only able to prove that if $h \neq g$ (so that the problem is nontrivial), then $|h \langle g \rangle| < |h|$.

I then looked at trying to prove $\langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle = \langle h \rangle$, or using the fact that since $h^{|g|} = e \in \langle g \rangle$, then $t = \{i > 0 \: |\: h^i \in \langle g \rangle\}$ is well defined, and tried to show $t=1$.  Using the DA, you get $1=qt+r$ for $0 \leq r < t$, so if you can show $h^{1-qt} \in \langle g \rangle$, then $r=0$, and $qt=1$, proving the claim (since $t \geq 1$).

However in all of these scenarios I was stumped.  I'm sure this is an extremely simple problem that I'm overcomplicating, so I'd be super appreciative for an explanation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $|h|=d\mid|g|.$ The hint is useless. $\langle g\rangle$ is cyclic hence contains a subgroup of order $d.$ By uniqueness, this subgroup is equal to $\langle h\rangle,$ so it contains $h.$

Comment: I like how elegant this is.

Comment: Thanks!  I was very confused on the hint.